# Is it possible to define a reusable function to be called in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to write my custom function to be imported into Jenkins instance and then used by many Jenkinsfiles in our company. Basically, I want to use it like this:

```
... Jenkinsfile goes here ...

myCustomFunc param1: "foo"
             param2: "bar"
             param3: 100500

... Jenkinsfile continues ...
```

What is the most efficient way to write and import custom reusable function into Jenkins? It would be better if I could write it in Groovy.